# Как правильно задеплоить web-приложение на tomcat на VDS?

Tags: java, tomcat, веб-сервер, развертывание, vds

Вопрос больше на понимание best practics.
Имеется простое Spring MVC web приложение с несколькими viewes. При локальной разработке\локальном tomcat, при запуске сервера из IDE, переход между станицами работает корректно (адреса типа localhost:8080/index, localhost:8080/welcome, etc.), но при деплое на VDS столкнулся с тем, что теперь переход происходит по адресам localhost:8080/APP_NAME/index, localhost:8080/APP_NAME/welcome, etc.
Соответственно два вопроса:

1. На сервере крутятся Apache и Tomcat, с помощью Redirect в .htaccess сделал точку входа с site.ru на site.ru:8080/index.  Правильно ли это?
2. Как обеспечить на сервере переход между страницами по тем же путям, что и в локальном деплое, без включения имени приложения? Нагуглил несколько путей, таких как замена root app на сервере своим приложением или редактирование файла server.xml, но считаю, что это не совсем правильно. Возможно ли добиться этого с помощью maven или дескрипторов развертывания? Если да, то буду благодарен за примеры.

Comment: 2) У каждого контейнера сервлетов есть свой способ задать contextpath, отличный от APP_NAME. Предположу что при локальной разработке запускаете приложение через среду разработки, которая знает как выполнить такую подмену. Вам нужно нагуглить как на tomcate-е деплоить приложение в ROOT. 
1) А из apach-а разумнее сделать revers-proxy, а не redirect. У апача даже есть какой-то модуль специально для сервлетов java, для лучшей производительности. Только серер-приложений java тоже должен понимать этот протокол. Не помню как называется, гуглите сами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на второй вопрос.
Так как в документации Tomcat в самом начале указано, что настоятельно НЕ рекомендуется размещать элементы непосредственно в файл server.xml, то 
добавил файл с именем ROOT.xml в /conf/Catalina/localhost/
Этот ROOT.xml переопределит настройки по умолчанию для корневого контекста установки tomcat для этого движка и хоста (Catalina и localhost).

Введите в файл ROOT.xml следующее:

```
<Context 
  docBase="<yourApp>" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```

Здесь  - это название приложения.

**Не забыть поменять права на файл, чтобы Tomcat мог его читать. Я просто поменял владельца.**

Теперь приложение является приложением по умолчанию и будет отображаться на http://localhost:8080

Однако есть один побочный эффект - приложение будет загружено дважды. Один раз для localhost:8080 и один раз для localhost:8080/yourApp. Чтобы исправить это, можно поместить свое приложение OUTSIDE /webapps и использовать относительный или абсолютный путь в теге ROOT.xml docBase. Что-то вроде этого;

```
<Context 
   docBase="/opt/mywebapps/<yourApp>" 
   path="" 
   reloadable="true" 
/>
```

Все заработало.